# GoDaddy how to direct web hosting to another server without affecting Windows Exchange Server

Tags: web-hosting, dns, godaddy

My domain is hosted on GoDaddy (Thats where I purchased it form). I have Windows Exchange server setup as CNAME data. My website is designed and hosted on a another server (Not GoDaddy). How do I just tell my domain to go to this server just for Website information? For an exmaple, I changed DNS settings on my domain to this Web hosting company's DNS Settings and it broke the link to my Windows Exchagne server. How do I tell the domain to go to this web hosting server ONLY for website requests?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have initially changed the NAMESERVERS which broke the Windows Exchange `CNAME`.

If the domain is hosted on GoDaddy then you need to access the DNS records, this is where the Windows Exchange `CNAME` is held.

You should see an `A` record entry like `A example.com 104.16.14.128`

`example.com` will be your domain, the IP will be the GoDaddy website hosting IP.

By changing the IP address to the new hosting account IP that hosts your new site will direct website users to the new server.

You may also see a www `A` record entry with a GoDaddy IP, if you see this `A` record then this also needs to be swapped with your new hosting IP.

If you don't see an `A` record for www then you should see a `CNAME` that points to the `A` record. Just leave that as it is.